# Twitter Bootstrap 3 keep Tab on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

There where multiple Questions and solutions for the Tab container should keep the last selected tab instead of refreshing the whole page and starting in the first tab again. But the solutions i had wont work with my page. Can someone help me out?
This is my JS

```
<script type="javascript">
$(function() { 
    // for bootstrap 3 use 'shown.bs.tab', for bootstrap 2 use 'shown' in the next line
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        // save the latest tab; use cookies if you like 'em better:
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
    });

    // go to the latest tab, if it exists:
    var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
    if (lastTab) {
        $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
</script>
```

And that's my HTML:

```
 <ul  id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="background-color: #3E98E4;">
   <li role="presentation"  class="active"><a href="#kunver" aria-controls="kunver" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 10%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3C97E4;">Kunden</a></li>

    <li role="presentation"><a href="#erter" aria-controls="erter" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 10%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3C97E4;">Termine</a></li>

    <a href="logout.php" ><button style="margin-top: 1%;margin-left:1%;
  background-color: #3E98E4;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</button></a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Where is you `#Tabcont` element?

Comment: This was and earlier test, has nothing to do here i should remove it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Well I've made few modifications to your code and it will be as below:

```
var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
if (lastTab) {
   $('li.active,.tab-pane.active').removeClass('active');
   //remove active class from both li and tabpane since it will be by default added at page load
   $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
   //add active to lastTab's parent li using closest
   $(lastTab).addClass('active');
   //also add active to lastTab
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/w8atqb49/4/)**

---

**UPDATE**

Using native `.tab('show')` method you can do it as below but again you need to remove `active class` from previous `default element`

```
var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
if (lastTab) {
  $('li.active,.tab-pane.active').removeClass('active');
  $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/w8atqb49/5/)**

Comment: Your solutions seems fine to me. But still it wont work when i imply it. where should i paste it in code? is it maybe because he's not calling it on reload? sorry i am not that good in JS.

Comment: See basically your try should work.. Bdw check for console errors in prior before I can give you exact solution..

Comment: I checked everything. No error. Could it be, that there something about that it's a php file? it checks first for a session(if user is logged in or not) and after that stands the html tags etc. and the header with all links to css, js and finally this js script. here is the whole section above: http://pastebin.com/WzwEfwP0

Comment: Also if possible keep you `script` tag at the end before `</body>` and then the `js code`

Comment: Did you try keeping the `scripts` before the `body` ends instead of  inside `head`?

Comment: Yes i did, it had no affect :/

Comment: Ok let me give you one last suggestion.. Try to replicate your problem **[in php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)** or **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)** and also with the data that has been rendered in browser.. Inspect the element and you will get `html`.. Is that good..?

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the hash:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

The url will be updated and when the refresh button is clicked it should open the correct tab.

Comment: It's still not working with this method :/ i don't know if something else is messing up this whole thing but i had a lot of solutions found in the internet and none of them worked.

Comment: I tried it on a page in a project I had open and it worked fine for me, are there any errors on the console or any other code you may have written that could be causing a problem? It would explain why nothing has worked from what you have tried so far. jQuery and bootstrap.js definitely included on the page etc.?

Comment: JQuery and Bootstrap are included. I can't tell if another code is conflicting with this part but i will overlook the whole page again. Thanks for that advise (No console errors).

Comment: I needed to add this bit so on refresh it would load the hashed tab: 
`// on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab`
`var hash = window.location.hash;`
`$('#config-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');`

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one tab in the page, you can use the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTab').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');        
    }
    $('#charts-tab').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('chartsactiveTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var chartsactiveTab = localStorage.getItem('chartsactiveTab');
    if(chartsactiveTab){
        $('#charts-tab a[href="' + chartsactiveTab + '"]').tab('show');        
    }     
});
</script>
```